# Constrain kernel filters to only have entries of -1, 0 or 1?

Tags: pytorch, torch, autoencoder

My autoencoder model learns the most common patterns in images with pixel values -1, 0 or 1. While my model runs well, the decoding falls into a local minima with float values between -1 and 1.

Is there anyway in Pytorch I can constrain the kernel filters to have entries -1, 0 or 1 to observe better learning capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

If your target values are discrete, it would probably make more sense to use a pixel-wise softmax over 3 classes while turning your reconstruction loss into cross entropy.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely *can* do this, but it's probably a bad idea. To constrain the weights to specific values you can after each training iteration simply set the weights to the values you want, e.g use [torch.clamp](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.clamp) to set them to the range [-1, 1]:

```
model.my_layer.weight.detach().clamp_(-1,1)
```

While the above approach might work in some instances, your question of discretizing the weights to only 3 possible values will be very hard to optimize using gradients, and will probably lead to little to no learning.